# What is the difference between @include and @match in userscripts?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

The [GreaseSpot page on metadata blocks](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block) says that the two are very similar but `@match` "sets more strict rules on what the `*` character means."  GreaseSpot then proceeds to [teach](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Include_and_exclude_rules) using `@include`, but Chrome examples like [this](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts) generally seem to use `@match` and indicate that `@include` is only supported for compatibility purposes; `@match` is preferred.

[Apparently](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts), `@include google.*` can run on google.evil.com while `@match google.*` cannot.
That one example is not sufficient to really see how the wildcards behave differently between these two, and better explanations are sought in answers here.

New GreaseMonkey scripts (Firefox) use `@include` by default while new TamperMonkey scripts (for e.g. Chrome) use `@match` by default.

What exactly are the differences between these two?

For example, how does each one handle wildcards?
Are there differences in cross-browser compatibility?
What reasons would someone have for choosing to use one over the other?

Comment: Just use include like everyone else. I've been doing it for years and have had no issues.

Comment: @MortenMoulder That's... uhh...  not necessarily a good thing. The question explicitly gives an example *of* one issue that might arise from it. Just because none of your users have gotten pwned from it (or, at least, none such have *made the news*) doesn't mean it's safe, especially not when "just use include" makes no mention of the necessary precautions one **must take** when using it, which the fine answer to this very good question expounds.

Comment: As of 2022 "Just use include" is even worse advice because it has been deprecated.  Tampermonkey is scheduled to remove support for it in 2023.  See [Convert deprecated `@include` with regular expression to `@match` in userscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71882835/convert-deprecated-include-with-regular-expression-to-match-in-userscript)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You cannot use regular expressions with `@match`, while you [can](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Include_and_exclude_rules#Regular_Expressions) with `@include`.

However, `@include` will give your users scarier security warnings about the script applying to all sites.

This is even though an `@include` expression permits you to be *more restrictive* about the sites a script applies to (e.g. specifying that part of a URL be numeric using the regex fragment `[0-9]+`, or using `^https?://` to apply to a script just those two schemes, instead of the more general non-regex globbing operator `*` used for each of those cases in `@match`, which causes the script to apply more broadly).

Comment: An example where `@match` wildcard is safer than `@include` wildcard can be found in [Tampermonkey forum](https://forum.tampermonkey.net/viewtopic.php?t=466): `@include http*://*.biniok.net` allows http://evil.de#biniok.net, `@match http*://*.biniok.net` does not.

Comment: @dkasak `@include http*://*.biniok.net` is interpreted as globs. To be interpreted as regular expression, it should be `@include /http*://*.biniok.net/`. In addition, `@include /http*://*.biniok.net/` doesn’t match http://evil.de/#biniok.net ; it matches something like `htt:/1biniok2net` or `httppppp://////xbiniokynet`

Answer (score 20):

## TL;DR: Rigidity

The most important difference is that `@match` is much more rigidly structured and restrictive than `@include`, which makes it the more "generally" secure (and preferred) variant. `@match` can be a little more complicated to use overall due to this rigidity, but `@include` may generate scarier warnings to the end user because it's easier to misuse.

The practical usage of the two can vary widely; the full breakdown of usage for each follows below.

---

## `@include` (and `@exclude`)

`@include` might be the directive most people are more familiar with (along with its opposing twin, `@exclude`, which has exactly the same syntax features). This is the more powerful and flexible directive compared to `@match`, largely because it can handle RegEx patterns. Its usage is also the most straightforward.

### Modes

You can specify `@include` patterns in two ways/ "modes":

#### Glob Mode

In "glob mode", asterisks `*` can be used as a [wildcard glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) to signify that *any* amount of characters, including zero, are allowed in a given spot in the pattern. Via [the GreaseMonkey docs](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Include_and_exclude_rules#Globs):

> For example: `http://www.example.com/foo/*` will match:
>
> - `http://www.example.com/foo/bar` and,
> - `http://www.example.com/foo/`
>
> but not:
>
> - `http://www.example.com/baz/`.

There's also a special pattern available just for `@include` that will match any top-level domain suffix: [`.tld`](https://sourceforge.net/p/greasemonkey/wiki/Script_injection_rules/#tld). A pattern like `@include https://www.example.tld/*` will match the given domain with [any valid, public TLD suffix](https://publicsuffix.org/list/), such as `.com`, `.org`, or `.co.uk`.

#### Regular Expression Mode

`@include` directives that start with a forward slash `/` will be interpreted as a regular expression, with all standard JavaScript RegEx features available:

```txt
// ==UserScript==
// @include     /^https?://www\.example\.com/.*$/
// @include     /^http://www\.example\.(?:org|net)//
// ==/UserScript==
```

A few notes:

- Due to JavaScript's RegEx interpretation, forward slashes `/` are not required to be escaped inside expressions.
- [Other special characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#using_special_characters) still need to be escaped.
- `@include` patterns are **always** treated as **case-insensitive**.
- Expressions not ending with the EOL token `$` **will implicitly allow trailing characters on matches**.

  - I.e. the expression is treated as if it ended with `.*`.
  - `@include /^https?://www\.google\.com/search/` **will** match `https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow`.

### Warnings

Keep in mind that the powerful & wide-encompassing nature of `@include` means that a browser cannot guarantee the target of a given script as well as it can with `@match`. This means that scripts using `@include` may trigger severe-sounding warnings for the user in some cases.

One of the most cited dangers of using `@include` is unintentional (or *maliciously in*tentional) URL matching; this can occur when `@include` patterns aren't scoped or understood properly, or when a bad actor crafts a URL to specifically trigger a script where it isn't intended to run.

Since non-RegEx wildcards can match any characters, anywhere in a URL, seemingly simple patterns can have unexpected matches. For example, one might expect `*://example.net/*` to only match URLs belonging to the `example.net` domain, but it will also match `https://evil.com/?http://example.net/`!

Some userscript managers have built-in protections to help mitigate attack vectors like these, but the possibility still exists, which makes `@include` potentially more dangerous than `@match`, which is designed to be largely immune to this style of attack.

---

## `@match`

The `@match` directive is a creation of Google for Chrome, designed to be a safer, more sandboxed version of the `@include` directive, with *much* more rigidity built-in.

Instead of allowing globs or RegEx, `@match` interprets a pattern as 3 parts: the *scheme*, the *host*, and the *path*. [Google's documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/match_patterns/) describes the basic syntax this way:

```txt
<url-pattern> := <scheme>://<host><path>
<scheme> := '*' | 'http' | 'https' | 'file' | 'ftp' | 'urn'
<host> := '*' | '*.' <any char except '/' and '*'>+
<path> := '/' <any chars>
```

Each part of the pattern carries its own caveats, and also **interprets wildcards `*` differently**.

### Scheme

The scheme portion of the URL pattern must either exactly match a scheme supported by the browser or be the wildcard `*`. Note, however, that the wildcard **does not** allow all schemes, but instead matches just `http` and `https`.

| Browser | Schemes Supported in Match Patterns |
| --- | --- |
| Chrome | `http`, `https`, `file`, `ftp`, or [`urn`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Name) |
| [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns#scheme) | `http`, `https`, `file`, `ftp`, [`ws`, `wss`](https://javascript.info/websocket), `data`, or (`chrome-`)`extension` |
| Safari | At least<sup>1</sup> `http` and `https` |

1. I can't find a comprehensive reference on what schemes Safari supports in manifests. [Mozilla tracks it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns#browser_compatibility) as missing all but `http` and `https`, but they lack a comprehensive list for other browsers (e.g. `urn` is missing, which Chrome supports), so Safari may still support other schemes.

A caveat to the wildcard here is that [in Firefox specifically](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns#scheme) (and potentially others, but notably *not* Chrome or Safari), the wildcard will also match WebSocket schemes `ws` and `wss`.

### Host

The host portion of the URL pattern can come in three styles:

- Fully explicit: `www.stackoverflow.com`
- Subdomain wildcard: `*.stackoverflow.com`
- Fully wildcard: `*`

The top-level domain suffix *cannot* be a wildcard (e.g. `www.stackoverflow.*`); [this is disallowed for security reasons](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/faq/#faq-dev-16). In order to match multiple TLD suffixes, a script will need to include a specific `@match` directive for each.

### Path

The path portion of the URL pattern is the most permissive, as the only rule is that it must start with a forward slash `/`. The rest can be any combination of characters and wildcards.

In this section, wildcards `*` act as a standard glob operator, simply matching 0 or more characters.

The value that gets matched against the path portion of the pattern is officially the *URL path* plus the *URL query string* (eg. In `google.com/search?q=test`, the query string is `q=test`), including the `?` between. This is a potential pitfall for patterns that aim to match the end of a given domain, since they may be foiled by an added query string.

Also note that the path does *not* include URL fragments (the part of the URL at the end that follows a hash `#`, e.g. `www.example.com#main`); `@match` directives ignore URL fragments by design to prevent abuse of unintentional matches.

---

#### A Word of Caution

It's fairly obvious, but it bears repeating that scripts should be careful to `@include` *exactly* and *exclusively* the URLs that the script is intended to be run on. Runaway scripts can range from minor annoyances to major problems; always double check that scripts are running only where they're supposed to be, and use `@exclude` to add guardrails if necessary or convenient.

Comment: note that the wildcard `*` in scheme will only match `http` and `https`.

Answer (score -2):

In userscripts, `@include` and `@match` are both metadata directives used to specify the URLs of web pages where the userscript should run. However, they have some differences in how they match URLs.

`@include` specifies a list of URLs where the userscript should run.
You can use wildcards like `*` to match multiple URLs or parts of URLs.
It is more flexible and allows for pattern matching.

`@match` specifies a single URL pattern where the userscript should run.
It is less flexible than `@include` because it doesn't support wildcards or pattern matching.
It's typically used for exact URL matches.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/11107541