# Is it possible to use RegEx at all with @match in userscripts?

Tags: regex, include, match, userscripts, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I've been getting a warning in my userscript to change from `@include` to `@match` as it may be depreciated in Manifest v3 (cannot find any evidence of this though).

However, @match supposedly does not support RegEx. At least according to this other question: [What is the difference between @include and @match in userscripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31817758/what-is-the-difference-between-include-and-match-in-userscripts)

Is it possible at all to use RegEx with @match? If so, how? I am including a .json array of strings in my script (via `@include https://url.json`) which I am running a RegEx expression against. To my understanding this is not possible with @match, only @include.

If not, is there are more modern and acceptable way for my script to make use of RegEx without displaying warnings because I am using @include?

Comment: No, it's not possible.